# Calling SQL Server stored procedure with result set and return value

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, sqldatareader

Is there a way to get a dataset and a return value from a SQL Server stored procedure with just one execution of the stored procedure?

Is there a way to get both in just one call?

TIA
Marcos Galvani

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

// Pick the stored procedure to be executed
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CustomersList02", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// Set the parameters and return value
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", email));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int)).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

// Open the connection
conn.Open();
```

If I do this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

I don't get the return value, but if I do this:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I don't get the result set.

Comment: After doing `cmd.ExecuteReader()` did you check the value of Return value parameter?

Comment: I did. it is null.

Comment: You can use output parameter instead of return parameter

Comment: Not what I need. but thanks for the advice.

Comment: For what it's worth, this way of accessing databases is very old.  You can use Dapper or even Entity Framework to easily execute stored procedures and get a return value, in a single call and with many fewer lines of code.

Comment: What does the stored procedure actually return? (If it's returning _data_ and not an error/status code, then I concur [it should be an output parameter instead](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single call.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
}

// getthe return value.
int returnValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value;
```

Comment: Vivek, your code does work. but why it does not work in my code? the using is make a difference?

Comment: because in one way you were not retrieving the return value and in another way `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows